# How to manage source code access with a self-hosted Git repo? (i.e. not Github)

Tags: git

In our organization, we are looking to set up a git server for our main project that users on our offline local network will be able to contribute to.

We want, however, the ability to prevent some users from accessing certain files while allowing others with e.g. certain privelleges access (maybe with a password). "Access" both refers to reading and writing access (although being able to set up both individually would be even better!)

Is this possible?

Comment: The simplest thing is to use a single OS-level user so that there are no permissions problems... now, about keeping files from being edited and so on, that can't be done just like that. Consider that when you are pushing things into the repo, you are not really playing with the files on the FS... rather, they are just objects on the repo. You might be able to get away with some of it by using a push hook (check revisions, who's committing? What files are modified? Ok, accepted).

Answer (score 1):

Basically no. What you're describing is not Git. Git does not traffic in files and it does not "provide access" to anything. It does not read or write files. It maintains a repository and you can serve that. The repository is commits that a user can sync locally with their own Git.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with just git, but there are additional tools you can set up to get such features. You could install [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html), pay from [bitbucket server](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/enterprise/data-center), or use [gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) for example. Although even those usually manage permissions per repository, not per file.